# ASP.NET Core MVC how to populate dropdown list with numbers 10,20,30,40,50...100. I generate 1,2,3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

I have seen similar examples where people need to populate with a list of object but all I would like to achieve is to have the numbers 10,20,30...100 in my `DropdownlistFor` in my view.

I use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.NumberOfTickets, 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
      .Select(i => new SelectListItem 
      { 
         Text = i.ToString(), 
         Value = i.ToString() 
      }))
```

Comment: If only the language provided some means of multiplication... if you could do simple maths in C# you could do something like `i * 10`...

Comment: `(i * 10)`. Is it a cheating way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to get steps of 10s:

```cs
Enumerable
  .Range(1, 10)
  .Select(i => i * 10)   // <- here is the clue others already suggested
  .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() })
```